# <marquee> tag not working with Angular 2 Interpolation

Tags: html, angularjs, angular2-template

When using marquee tag with Interpolation , text not moving as expected , i saw somewhere that marquee is now deprecated html tag , Is there in alternative available.

**This works Fine**

```
<marquee direction="left" speed="slow" behavior="loop">
North Korea will close main nuclear test site in May, South says              
</marquee>
```

**But text not moving in this one**

```
<marquee direction="left" speed="slow" behavior="loop">
{{BreakingNews}}             
</marquee>
```

**This also same, text not moving**

```
<marquee direction="left" speed="slow" behavior="loop" [innerHTML]='BreakingNews'>       
</marquee>
```

Comment: its working fine. Check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sniu61?file=app%2Fapp.component.html . Share ur component code

Comment: If it's long text cannot move smoothly ...<marquee   behavior="loop" direction="left" speed="slow"   onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
{{companyNews}} // component.ts as text 
</marquee>

Answer (score 0):

When you make marquee tag on load, it gets empty after some time, when your dynamic content gets added.

You just need to add a `'&nbsp;'` space to the marquee tag before calling the dynamic code.

This creates a space which is not visible in your frontend, abd your marquee tag is not empty on load anymore. This works fine.